# Using PRIORVALUE function on custom object parent relationship in process builder not working?

Tags: process-builder, relationships, platform-bug

Let's say I want to do some action when a Contact is reparented from an Account of a certain `Type`.  I've created a process with this condition:

```
ISCHANGED([Contact].AccountId) &&
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE([Contact].Account.Type), 'Industry')
```

This seems to work fine and my action fires.  However, if I try to do the exact same thing with a Custom Object relationship, it doesn't seem to work at all.

```
ISPICKVAL( PRIORVALUE([Account].Premier_Status__r.Assignment_Type__c), 'Advocate')
```

Compiles fine, but never fires (I've quadruple checked values match, test record is setup properly and action functions properly).

Anyone know if this should be possible?  Seems like a platform bug.

### Update

In an attempt to create the simplest possible scenerio, I created a new custom object (`Foo__c`) with one picklist field called `Bar__c` (w/ values "One" & "Two".  I added a lookup to `Foo__c` from the Contact and created 2 Foo record (one with each value).  I updated the first Process Builder (which is definitely working) to reference this custom Object instead of the account.

```
  ISCHANGED([Contact].Foo__c) &&
  ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE([Contact].Foo__r.Bar__c), 'One')
```

And no dice...  Definitely seems as though Process Builder is treating Custom Objects different from Standard.

Comment: Moving this conversation [to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73250/discussion-on-question-by-nsjonas-using-priorvalue-function-on-custom-object-par).

Comment: I am facing the same problem. @NSjonas, did you find any solution.

Comment: I believe the solution was do it in a trigger ;)